# What does the insertEntry in YOUTUBE API return?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

This is what we use to upload a Video to YouTube using YouTube API.

$newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');

Once we upload, how can we get the unique code of the Video we just uploaded ?? 
What I mean is, in the url, 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBI3lc18k8Q

"pBI3lc18k8Q" is the unique code for the video. So, how to get this for the video we just uploaded??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this code after you upload it:

```
// Assuming that $videoEntry is the object that was returned during the upload
$state = $videoEntry->getVideoState();

if ($state) {
  echo 'Upload status for video ID ' . $videoEntry->getVideoId() . ' is ' .
    $state->getName() . ' - ' . $state->getText() . "\n";
  } else {
    echo "Not able to retrieve the video status information yet. " . 
      "Please try again later.\n";
}
```

Comment: Very good thank you, `$newVideoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$videoEntry->getVideoId();`

Answer (score 2):

You've got your unique code in $newEntry! ;)